# Getting Internal Server Error when sending POST request with an image file to database using React JS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, file-upload, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an image using React JS and REST API with Laravel as backend.

I have a Partner model that has a name and a logo. I created a form to enter its name and logo.

When I enter just the name of the partner and submit, I find the new partner added to the database.

But when I try to upload the partner's logo I get this error: POST http://localhost:8000/api/eventpartners 500 (Internal Server Error)

And on my browser, when I go to inspect->Network I find this error: {message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Here is the AddPartnerForm.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton';
import axios, { post } from 'axios';



export default class AddPartnerForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newPartnerData: {
        partnerlogoimage: '',
        partnername: ''
      },
      partnerlogouploaded: false
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.addPartner = this.addPartner.bind(this)
    this.onUpload = this.onUpload.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      newPartnerData: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  }

  onUpload(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      newPartnerData: {
        ...prev.newPartnerData,
        partnerlogoimage: file,
      },
      partnerlogouploaded: true
    }));
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.addPartner();
    console.log(this.state.newPartnerData)
  }

  addPartner() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/eventpartners';
    return axios.post(url, this.state.newPartnerData)
      .then((response) => {
        let { partners } = this.state;
        partners.push(response.data);
        this.setState({
          newPartnerData: {
            partnerlogoimage: '',
            partnername: '',
          }
        })
      })
  }


  render() {
    const newPartnerData = this.state.newPartnerData;
    const partnerlogouploaded = this.state.partnerlogouploaded;
    let partnerlogo;
    if (partnerlogouploaded) {
      partnerlogo = <img style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} src={this.state.partnerlogoimage} />;
    } else {
      partnerlogo = <Skeleton variant="rect" width={200} height={200} />;
    }
    return (
      <form >
        <TextField
          name="partnername"
          autoFocus
          margin="dense"
          id="name"
          label="Partner's name"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <input accept="image/*"
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          id="contained-button-partner-logo"
          name="partnerlogoimage"
          multiple
          type="file"
          diplay="none"
          onChange={this.onUpload} />
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-partner-logo" className="upload-button">
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span" >
            Upload Partner Logo
        </Button>
        </label>
        <Box width={200} height={200} marginRight={0.5} my={5}>
          {partnerlogo}
        </Box>
        <Button type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" component="span" >
          Add
        </Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm using Laravel as the backend of this app.

This is the EventPartnerController.php file if it helps:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Eventpartner;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventpartnerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $eventpartners = Eventpartner::all();
        return $eventpartners;
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->all();
        $eventpartner = new Eventpartner();
        $eventpartner->event_id = $request->event_id;
        $eventpartner->partnername = $request->partnername;
        $eventpartner->partnerlogoimage = $request->partnerlogoimage;
        $eventpartner -> save();
        return response()->json($eventpartner);
    }

    
}
```

And this is the routing file api.php :

```
<?php
Use App\Eventpartner;
Use App\Http\Controllers\EventpartnerController;

Route::get('eventpartners', function() {
    return Eventpartner::all();
});
Route::post('eventpartners', 'EventpartnerController@store');
```

If there's any missing code that I should add to this question please tell me in the comments.

Comment: when are you getting error? upload or submit?

Comment: When I submit. and in the console.log it returns the partner's data that I entered in json format correctly.

Comment: let { partners } = this.state; - `partners` not present in the state. Next line will fail

Comment: How should I modify it?

Comment: I need to understand the use case. Do you really need to push the partners in the state ?

Comment: I'll delete those 2 lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223685/discussion-between-uks-and-ala-ben-aicha).

Comment: Also post code for laravel backend where you are doing conversion!

Comment: How to do that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Should I show you the partnerController code?

Comment: The controller that is responsible for that route and conversion logic (if you doing conversion in backend)

Comment: I added the controller and the api.php files

Comment: Did you try this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_json_encode.asp

Comment: I added it to the store function in the controller like this : return response()->json_encode($eventpartner);
But didn't work.

Comment: like this? : return response()->{!! str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($eventpartner)) !!};

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223689/discussion-between-suleman-ahmad-and-ala-ben-aicha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending **partnerLogoImage** in a string type but **images**
should always be send in **Blob** type to the backend. I think your backend is fine but the problem is on **Frontend** side where you are not using **Blob** type for **image (partnerLogoImage)**. Please send the image in Blob type in the **axios** POST request and it will work fine.